# Angularjs 2, split an Edit button into a Save and Cancel button

Tags: angularjs

I am developing a front-end App using AngularJS 2, my question is, I have an Edit button on a landing page, once the Edit button is clicked, it suppose to render  a a Save and Cancel buttons, any ideas?

Comment: Please elaborate by adding some work of yours.

Comment: On the user information page, there are Security Question and Security Answer columns, Security Question contain a list of dropdown, Security Answer is a simple input column, at first they are greyed out with an Edit button, once the Edit is selected, an Edit button is replace with a Save and Cancel buttons

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-if or ng-show to show the save and cancel buttons based on a property that is turned to true when the edit button is clicked.

Comment: Thx...work now... I am using *ngIf with an "!isEdit" flag